# Using compiled bindings with Prism

Tags: forms, xamarin, binding, prism, compiled

I want to use compiled bindings in my Xamarin Forms app in combination with Prism.

I created a small xamarin forms app with a simple view, viewmodel and prism (prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"). Classic binding works as expected.
How should I implemented compiled binding without creating the binding context twice?

Classic binding with prism: HomePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="CompiledBinding.Views.HomePage">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage>
```

HomePageViewModel.cs:

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CompiledBinding.ViewModels
{
    public class HomePageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        string _name = "Compiled binding test";

        public HomePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            var nav = navigationService;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                // Do something
                Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd hh:mm:ss");

                return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
            });
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the binding context to the xaml page again, is not an option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:CompiledBinding.ViewModels"
             x:Class="CompiledBinding.Views.HomePage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomePageViewModel">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:HomePageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage>
```

Besides of defining the binding context again, it also results in the error: no public parameterless constructor.

Do I oversee something? Does anyone know how to work with compiled bindings together with prism?

Comment: I wll come back asap if have any result.

Comment: As I see it, compiled bindings requires a parameterless constructor as it has no way of knowing what to supply for each of the parameters as it will try to instantiate and manage itself. It seems compiled bindings will not work for Prism atm.

Comment: Can you post your sample on a public repository I would like to try something.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Any guidance would be much appreciated before I have a crack at it!

Comment: No, I still didn't figure it out